# Get Column Name from 2 tables based on Lookup Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, lookup

I have 2 tables and a lookup table for relations:

TG

```
ID | TG_CODE | TG_NAME | DATE_TIME_CREATED | DATE_TIME_MODIFIED
```

and

RG

```
ID | RG_CODE | ASSN | R_LEADER | DATE_TIME_CREATED | DATE_TIME_MODIFIED
```

and a lookup table:

TG_RG_ID

```
ID | TG_ID | RG_ID | DATE_TIME_CREATED | DATE_TIME_CREATED
```

where RG_ID is child of parent TG_ID

I would like to get the ID, RG_CODE that are in the lookup table based on TG_ID provided.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: If I understood: 

`DECLARE @TG_ID_PROVIDED AS INT = <<YOUR TG_ID VALUE>>

SELECT  TG_RG_ID.ID,
   TG_RG_ID.RG_CODE
FROM  TG_RG_ID (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN RG (NOLOCK)
ON   TG_RG_ID.RG_ID = RG.ID
WHERE  TG_RG_ID.TG_ID = @TG_ID_PROVIDED`